# Usage of _itow_s and _ltow_s

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to use [_itow_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [_ltow_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfh48htd.aspx) of MSVC in VC8. But I am not getting what to pass as length of buffer to these two APIs.

MSDN is giving me the below explanation for _itow_s

```
[in] sizeInCharacters
Size of the buffer in single-byte characters or wide characters.
```

for _ltow_s

```
sizeOfstr 
Size of the str in bytes for _ltoa_s or words for _ltow_s.
```

So Will it be fine, If i pass the number of wide characters (`WCHAR`) as length of the buffer into these two APIs like below

```
WCHAR buf[20];
_itow_s(11L, buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(WCHAR), 10);
_ltow_s(11L, buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(WCHAR), 10);
```

Comment: The statement is generalized for all functions, and it's up to you do deduce the meaning of it. For these functions, it is about WCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

`_itow_s` and `_ltow_s` expect this parameter to be the length of `WCHAR`s. Your `buf` is of type `WCHAR` and you are passing the number of `WCHAR`s, hence it looks correct.